# OMNeT++ buffer design

Tags: c++, omnet++

I'm trying to implement a FIFO buffer as a OMNeT++ node. However I'm stuck deciding the best way to model it.

The buffer has basically one input gate and one output gate. What I want to obtain is that the sender is not allowed to send() messages to the buffer when it is full. How can I get this information without having the buffer's pointer? I identified some workarounds for it, however I would like to know if there is a best practice for this kind of problems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peeking into the other module is fine as that's the easiest way to implement this out of band communication. The queueinglib example in OMNeT++ does this also with the `Server`, `PassiveQueue` module pair. They are tightly coupled  and communicate this information through predefined interfaces (IServer, IPassiveQueue).

Tips: you should look up the other module through the connection and not through the actual module name and you should also check whether the module has the type you expect.